# Пишу pipeline jenkins который создает image docker из dockerfile и пушит его на dockerhub

Tags: docker, jenkins, push

pipeline состоит из трех шагов.Первые два отлично работают.Возникла проблема с отправкой готового image в свой репозиторий на dockerhub.
вот весь третий шаг

```
stage('Deploy image') {
            steps {
                script{
                    docker.withRegistry('https://hub.docker.com', registryCredential ) {
                        dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
                         dockerImage.push('latest')
```

в environment прописано что registryCredential= 'dockerhub'(dockerhub это логин и пароль от моего аккаунта на  https://hub.docker.com)

Выдает следующую ошибку

```
$ docker login -u tilk9092 --password-stdin https://hub.docker.com
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение следующее,в энвах объявляется переменная

```
dockerImage = ''
```

Соответственно последний шаг выглядит так

```
stage('Deploy image') {
        steps {
            script{
                docker.withRegistry('', registryCredential ) {
                    dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
                     dockerImage.push('latest')
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько знаю, второй аргумент у `docker.withRegistry(...)` - это ID credentials.

Добавлен ли в "Credentials -> System -> Global credentials -> Add Credentials" credential с ID `dockerhub` с вашим логином и паролем к Docker Hub?

[Больше информации тут.](https://tutorials.releaseworksacademy.com/learn/building-your-first-docker-image-with-jenkins-2-guide-for-developers)

Comment: Да,конечно.Я же написал что registryCredential= 'dockerhub'(dockerhub это логин и пароль от моего аккаунта на https://hub.docker.com)

Comment: Если попробовать не по паролю, а по access token?

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/

Comment: ровно тот же результат,изначально в настройках и был токен.Мне уже подсказали решение